# Why do I need to do a deep copy when using prevState instead of a simple setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The code you see in below works fine when I use `setState` but as soon as I use `prevState`, it breaks!, I don't understand why, of course I know that if I copy the `buttonList` object like this :

```
const newButtonList = prevState.buttonList.map(item => {
  return {...item}
}
```

this will fix the problem, but i still don't understand why the previous solution doesn't work !
Here is the full code and a sandbox link :
https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-christian-fb3ho?file=/src/Demo.js
code :
**onClick1 works but onClick2 doesn't work correclt**y

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";

class Demo extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    buttonList: [
      {
        key: "button1",
        enabled: false
      },
      {
        key: "button2",
        enabled: false
      }
    ]
  };

  onClick1 = (callerKey) => {
    const newButtonList = [...this.state.buttonList];

    const found = newButtonList.find((item) => item.key === callerKey);
    found.enabled = !found.enabled;

    this.setState({ buttonList: newButtonList });
  };

  onClick2 = (callerKey) => {
    this.setState((prevstate) => {
      const newButtonList = [...prevstate.buttonList];

      const found = newButtonList.find((item) => item.key === callerKey);
      found.enabled = !found.enabled;

      return {
        buttonList: newButtonList
      };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          onClick={() => this.onClick1("button1")}
          style={{ cursor: "pointer", marginBottom: "100px" }}
        >
          {`Button1 click on me (${this.state.buttonList[0].enabled})`}
        </div>
        <div
          onClick={() => this.onClick2("button2")}
          style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
        >
          {`Button2 click on me (${this.state.buttonList[1].enabled})`}
        </div>
        ;
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Demo;
```

Comment: The reason is the codesandbox runs in `<StrictMode>`, this means state updates are being called twice. The first handler races itself and therefore "works", the second changes the boolean twice, from false to true, then back to false. This came up before (which means this is basically a dupe, but I'm too lazy to search for the dupe right now)

Comment: @Yousaf That's weird because i first encountered this problem in my own code in VS Code with react `17.0.2` and after that I reproduced the problem in `Codesandbox`, so I don't believe the sandbox is the problem

Comment: If you use `found.enabled = true` instead, you'll find both "work".

Comment: @Yousaf, @ChrisG yep, removing `StrictMode` fixes the issue and onClick1 works just like onClick2, now that makes sense

Comment: @ChrisG _"the second changes the boolean twice, from false to true, then back to false"_ - i just verified that removing `StrictMode` resolves the issue BUT i don't think `StrictMode` resets the state. I could be wrong but still, i am not sure if `StrictMode` will reset it from true to false. I logged the state with `StrictMode`; handler is called twice as expected BUT `found.enabled` is `false` in both logs.

Comment: @Yousaf I was wondering the same, i know removing `StrictMode` solves it but logging the results i don't understand why is it that `StrictMode` is really doing to cause this

Comment: If you look [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects): "Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions: [...] State updater functions (the first argument to `setState`)" - running `x.y = !x.y` twice when `y` is a bool will leave you with the original value. (nowhere did I say StrictMode "resets the state" @Yousaf)

Comment: I have also noticed that logging `found` after mutating it in the second handler gives different output in codesandbox's console and the chrome's console: `found.enabled` is false in codesandbox's console and true in chrome's console.

Comment: @Yousaf I think its because of this that we don't see the result we want when we use console.log, "Starting with React 17, React automatically modifies the console methods like console.log() to silence the logs in the second call to lifecycle functions. However, it may cause undesired behavior in certain cases where a workaround can be used"

Comment: @AliAhmadi yes i am aware of that. I used `console.dir` method.

Comment: Despite all our discussion, you shouldn't be mutating the state like your are.

Comment: Ok, good find @ChrisG. `StrictMode` becoming more useful, and yet more cryptic.